# Nested Controllers and routes

Tags: php, laravel

I'm creating a dashboard where the user can create **Clients**

Each Client will have: Categories, Employees, ...
Now I'm wondering how to structure the routes.

For example if I create the following: (pseudo code)

```
Route::get('clients/{id}/');
Route::get('clients/{id}/categories');
Route::get('clients/{id}/categories/{category}');
Route::get('clients/{id}/categories/{category}/questions/{question}');
```

This seems like a lot of unnecessary parameters..

How do you guys go about this? I really want to split the categories on a seperate page, the employees on a seperate page.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

in all of my projects, i avoid using a lot of nested entities in the URL, so i access each one apart, this was also recommended by @jeffrey_way at Laracasts, the training website for laravel.
so, i would do the following:

```
Route::get('clients/{id}/');
Route::get('categories/{client_id}');
Route::get('categorie/{category}');   //not that i have removed the plural s from categorie(s)
Route::get('question/{question}');
```

Good luck

Comment: thank you, do you know in what lesson jeffrey explains this?

Comment: if i remember well, this training: [laravel 5.4 from scratch](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017)

Answer (score 1):

It honestly depends on how big your application is going to become, I would probably group them, so still keeping the same structure.

```
Route::group('clients/{id}', function()
{

    Route::get('/');

    Route::group('categories', function()
    {

        Route::get('/');
        Route::get('{category}');
        Route::get('{category}/questions/{question}');
    })
})
```

Same as yours but I feel it a little cleaning for later if you expand on the categories or clients.

Answer (score 0):

Here in such case I would rather prefer to use only one route will all parameters as in `GET` method. So, I would have add just one param as bellow:

`Route::get('client/create', 'ClientController@store');`

So, all the parameters will be maintained by the `store` method of `ClientController` like below:

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $category = $request->get('category')
    //......
    //get other get parameters like this when required
}
```

When I need to trigger this route I would just do something like below:

`<a href="{{url('client/create').'?category=1&question=2'}}">Create link</a>`

As you know, we can pass our parameters here using our old global friend `GET` variable.